# Buscar, Hallar, Encontrar Datos de Columna en Google Sheets o Excel 365

Tags: excel

[image: print de ejemplo]

Hola, buen día. Solicito su ayuda por favor. Tengo la columna B en Google Sheet GS o Excel 365, con el nombre de negocio.
El ejemplo es con GS. Quiero saber cómo puedo buscar palabras en la columna B, de una lista. Por ejemplo HOTEL y escribirla en la columna C, si no esta escribir "OTROS".
Esa es la primera parte del problema, que ya está resuelto.
La segunda es: quiero incluir otras palabras clave de B en C, en el ejemplo RESIDENCIAS Y HOSTAL. Si hay varias, escribirlas separadas por un espacio. Si no encuentra ninguna escribir OTROS. La pregunta es, cuál sería la fórmula o la función?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Siempre agrega lo que intentaste, esta pagina no es un servicio de haganlo por mi...

Answer (score 1):

Para buscar palabras en la columna B y escribirlas en la columna C, puedes utilizar la función IF y la función SEARCH en Google Sheets o la función IF y la función FIND en Excel 365. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo en Google Sheets:
En la celda C1, puedes utilizar la siguiente fórmula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("HOTEL", B1)), "HOTEL", "OTROS")
```

Esto buscará la palabra "HOTEL" en la celda B1. Si la encuentra, escribirá "HOTEL" en la celda C1. Si no la encuentra, escribirá "OTROS".
Para incluir otras palabras clave en la columna C, puedes utilizar la función IF y la función CONCATENATE en Google Sheets o la función IF y la función CONCATENATE en Excel 365. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo en Google Sheets:
En la celda C1, puedes utilizar la siguiente fórmula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("HOTEL", B1)), "HOTEL", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("RESIDENCIAS", B1)), CONCATENATE("RESIDENCIAS ", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("HOSTAL", B1)), "HOSTAL", "OTROS")), "OTROS"))
```

Esto buscará las palabras "HOTEL", "RESIDENCIAS" y "HOSTAL" en la celda B1. Si encuentra "HOTEL", escribirá "HOTEL" en la celda C1. Si encuentra "RESIDENCIAS" pero no encuentra "HOSTAL", escribirá "RESIDENCIAS OTROS" en la celda C1. Si no encuentra ninguna de las palabras clave, escribirá "OTROS" en la celda C1.

Comment: Muchas gracias @PabloXD por la respuesta. Lo que se quiere es que si encuentra HOTEL escriba HOTEL, si encuentra HOSTAL escriba HOSTAL, y así sucesivamente. Si no encuentra ninguna, que escriba OTROS y si encuentra varias que las escriba separadas por un espacio. OTROS  es únicamente para cuando no haya palabras clave.

Comment: Sabes que usar una IA para responder pregutnas esta prohibido, no?

Comment: =SI(ESBLANCO(B2), "OTROS",
    SI(ESNUMERO(HALLAR("HOTEL", B2)), "HOTEL",
        SI(ESNUMERO(HALLAR("HOSTAL", B2)), "HOSTAL",
            SI(ESNUMERO(HALLAR("RESIDENCIAS", B2)), "RESIDENCIAS",
                SI(ESNUMERO(HALLAR("HACIENDA", B2)), "HACIENDA",
                    "OTROS"))))) -- Esta es otra forma de encontrar las palabras clave, funciona bien. Ahora la pregunta es, en caso que haya varias palabras clave, c'omo concatenarlas?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, estoy haciendo una pregunta, que tiene como 3 partes, las he ido solucionando con los recursos de Internet y mucho tiempo, pero aun no se ha respondido, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, sobre todo porque no soy programador. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @VictorHerrera tu pregunta no es bien vista en su formato actual en este sitio. De igual forma, esta respuesta contesta tu pregunta. no entiendo de que otras cosas hablas.